# MySQL calculating distance (simple solution)

Tags: mysql, select

I have the next query for getting addresses within a given distance and given postal code. Distance is calculated, based upon longitude and latitude data.

In this example i have replaced the user-input for just values (lat=52.64, long=6.88 en desired distance=10km)

the query:

```
SELECT *,
ROUND( SQRT( POW( ( (69.1/1.61) * ('52.64' - latitude)), 2) + POW(( (53/1.61) * ('6.88' - longitude)), 2)), 1) AS distance
FROM lp_relations_addresses distance
WHERE distance < 10
 ORDER BY `distance`  DESC
```

gives  unknown column distance as error message.
when leaving out the where clausule i get every record of the table including their calculated distance. In this case i have to fetch the whole table.

How do i get only the desired records to fetch??

Thanks in advance for any comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in the select clause from another part of the sql statement.  You need to put the whole expression in your where clause:

```
WHERE
    ROUND( SQRT( POW( ( (69.1/1.61) * ('52.64' - latitude)), 2)
        + POW(( (53/1.61) * ('6.88' - longitude)), 2)), 1) < 10
```

A cleaner solution would be to use a sub-query to generate the calculated data:

```
  SELECT *, distance
    FROM (
       SELECT *,
           ROUND( SQRT( POW( ( (69.1/1.61) * ('52.64' - latitude)), 2)
               + POW(( (53/1.61) * ('6.88' - longitude)), 2)), 1) AS distance
           FROM lp_relations_addresses
       ) d
   WHERE d.distance < 10
ORDER BY d.distance DESC
```

Demo: http://www.sqlize.com/q96p2mCwnJ

Comment: Thanks again! it's time for me to sleep:) This problem was much too easy to solve.....

Comment: Tomorrow i will try your cleaner solution and compare them with Explain, many thanks again, your contribution saved a lot of hours for me!

Comment: @Terradon: I would take a look at `Ilmari Karonen`'s solution as well as it might be more efficient.

Comment: @mellamokb hi, thanks for your answer, how can i convert this value to Km?

Answer (score 3):

As [mellamokb notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718785/mysql-calculating-distance-simple-solution/7718815#7718815), you can't reference column aliases in the `WHERE` clause.  [You can, however, do it in a `HAVING` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html):

```sql
SELECT *,
  ROUND( SQRT( POW( ( (69.1/1.61) * ('52.64' - latitude)), 2) +
         POW(( (53/1.61) * ('6.88' - longitude)), 2)), 1) AS distance
FROM lp_relations_addresses
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

Ps. If you have lots of addresses, you might want to consider optimizing the query by ruling out some of them early.  For example, with suitable indexes, the following version might be considerably faster:

```sql
SELECT *,
  ROUND( SQRT( POW( ( (69.1/1.61) * ('52.64' - latitude)), 2) +
         POW(( (53/1.61) * ('6.88' - longitude)), 2)), 1) AS distance
FROM lp_relations_addresses
WHERE latitude > '52.64' - 10 / (69.1/1.61)
  AND latitude < '52.64' + 10 / (69.1/1.61)
  AND longitude > '6.88' - 10 / (53/1.61)
  AND longitude < '6.88' + 10 / (53/1.61)
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

Comment: +1 Tho you need to have the `ORDER BY` clause *after* the `HAVING` clause, then it works beautifully: http://www.sqlize.com/7e8TpPqiuj

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution! saved me some headache

Answer (score 2):

You are aliasing the calculation as 'distance', but you are also aliasing table 'lp_relations_addresses' as 'distance'. Try giving them a different name like this:

```
SELECT *,
ROUND( SQRT( POW( ( (69.1/1.61) * ('52.64' - latitude)), 2) + POW(( (53/1.61) * ('6.88' - longitude)), 2)), 1) AS distance
FROM lp_relations_addresses addr
WHERE distance < 10
ORDER BY `distance`  DESC
```

Comment: I tried your code too, but distance in where clausule gives an unknown column distance as error.

Comment: Well spotted on the table alias clash, but as mellamokb notes, you can't use an alias in a *where*, but you can do this in a *having* as Ilmari notes ...